# How can I pull in data from other controllers/tables into one list?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails project where users sign up and login. Users will create "Music" so I have a "Music" controller, the user will fill in a title, and upload their MP3. Every user can do this -- this is dandy.

When a user logs in I want them to see everyone's uploaded music in a nice list view at http://example.org/explore. I will have some "latest additions since your last login" somewhere on the sidebar of this "explore" page in the future among some other features.

My question is, should I create a controller called "Explore" with an index action for this listing with something like the following?

```
class ExploresController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @music = Music.all
  end

  def show
  end
end
```

I thought this might be the right way to do this but it seems odd to have the "Explore" controller be using all of the actions you'd typically see in the "Music" controller. The Music controller is going to be CRUD for the current_user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily have the `music#index` method available to everyone and put user authentication on the CRUD methods. That way everyone can see all the uploaded music on the `/music` page, but only the owner of each one can alter them.

If users need an easy way to see a list of use their own mp3s then you can just use a nested resource, so it would be available at `/users/:id/music`.

If you need some more info on how to implement that stuff then leave a comment. The specifics would depend on what (if any) authentication systems you were using.

Comment: I am using devise. Can I not just create a UsersController with devise and put all the User specific music info there and delegate the Music controller for what it is used for and that is to list the music in the system instead?

Comment: You could, but it wouldn't really be keeping with Rails best practises. The Music controller should be dealing with all the CRUD operations to do with music objects, not just listing them. It doesn't seem to make much sense to put them into the UsersController just because they require a logged in user. If you are using Devise then it's very simple to just require authentication for some methods and not others, just put `before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => :index` at the top of the MusicController.

Comment: This is what i thought of doing, I guess I was second guessing myself, thanks Tom

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look a Rails way.

Use same Music controller( if it's just a CRUD [inherited_resources](https://rubygems.org/gems/inherited_resources) is your choice ) with [has_scope](https://rubygems.org/gems/has_scope) gem and manage user access with [cancan](https://rubygems.org/gems/cancan).

This way you have a 5lines MusicController and no any additional controlers

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly fine to add an 'explore' action to the Music controller.

As to whether or not a new controller is warranted, how much in common does the Explore page you have in mind have common with functions from the Music controller?  Can they share partials and helpers?  Will they utilize the same callbacks?

If your only plan is to list all from another model in the new controller as shown, then I would say the answer is straightforward:  keep in the in the Music controller.